# Attempting to run a FastAPI application on CentOS 7 but getting a module 'asyncio' error

Tags: python, linux, pip, fastapi, centos7

I am attempting to run a simple FastAPI application on CentOS 7 but getting some errors. I will include some more details for context:

Python Version - 3.6.8
pip version - 9.0.3

I am running the application with this command: `python3 -m uvicorn main:app`

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    uvicorn.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 435, in main
    run(app, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 461, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'
```

I was initially getting this error - `/home/centos/fast_api/fastapi-tutorial/python3-venv/bin/python3: No module named uvicorn` but after installing uvicorn via `pip3 install uvicorn`, I now get the "module 'asyncio' error"

Any help would be great

I have tried enabling a python virtual environment on the server but I still get the same error.

Could this be an issue with the Python version?

Comment: `asyncio.run` was added in Python3.7, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this. I was able to get this working by upgrading both python and pip.

I upgraded python to 3.9

Upgraded pip using - `/usr/local/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI [requires Python 3.7+](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi/), it's not compatible with your interpreter.

In your case the app fails because the `asyncio.run()` function was added in Python 3.7.

Comment: I upgraded to python 3.9 and ran the command `python3.9 -m uvicorn main:app` but i now get the following error `/usr/local/bin/python3.9: No module named uvicorn`. Uvicorn is installed

Comment: Are you sure uvicorn is installed for Python 3.9? What's the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: Uvicorn should be installed. When I run `pip3 --version` I get `pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: I upgraded pip so when i run `pip3.9 --version` , this is my result - `pip 23.0.1 from /home/centos/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)` 

However when i still run `python3.9 -m uvicorn main:app`, I still get the error `/usr/local/bin/python3.9: No module named uvicorn`

Comment: Try using pip that comes with your venv, not the global pip. It should be in the same dir as python venv executable